# To get table name and details using just the column name in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

can anyone help me in getting the table name and details from an SQL database whose column name is just known to me ?

Comment: Review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html then write query.

Comment: Thanks for the link but can you tell me exactly how can I perform the query.

Comment: A simple select with a filter on column name would do.

Comment: Please give me the syntax it is not working with - SHOW COLUMNS LIKE '%col_name%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can get information about your table from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'your-column-name'
```

Comment: I have a doubt if it works with MySQL or not? Although I have used it for SQL Server but what about MySQL?

Comment: @RohanSrivastwa - I tested it on my local MySQL installation and it works. Take a look at the [bottom of the page in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html) and you'll see an example using this syntax.